# Retrieving multiple pinned messages with Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to use Telethon to download multiple pinned messages from a group using the following code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, types

async def getPinnedMessages():
    async with TelegramClient('MySession', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        messages = await client.get_messages('MyGroupChat', ids=types.InputMessagePinned())
```

The problem is that this returns only a single message, even if there are multiple pinned messages. Any suggestions on what I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`InputMessagesFilterPinned`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/input_messages_filter_pinned.html):

```py
for message in client.iter_messages(chat, filter=types.InputMessagesFilterPinned()):
    ...  # use message
```